# Multi-Level inheritance and Versioning issue in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I seem to be having an issue when calling up the history of a versioned SQLAlchemy class.
I have the following inheritance structure setup:

```
Node(Versioned, Base)
Specimen(Node)
Animal(Specimen)
```

If I attempt to fetch the animal history using the query generated by :

```
AnimalHistory = self.__history_mapper__.class_
q = object_session(self).query(AnimalHistory).filter(AnimalHistory.id == self.id).order_by(AnimalHistory.version.desc())

logger.debug(q)
```

I get the following query:

```
SELECT bla bla #trimmed for brevity                                                                                                                                                                    FROM node_history 
JOIN specimen_history ON node_history.id = specimen_history.id AND node_history.version = specimen_history.version 
JOIN animal_history ON specimen_history.id = animal_history.id 
WHERE animal_history.id = 28 
ORDER BY animal_history.version DESC
```

Basically, I seem to be missing the appropriate "AND" statement on the animal_history JOIN.
Because of this, I get an unwanted cartesian product between animal and (specimen, node)

Could anyone point out the modification needed inside history_meta.py in order to fix this ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was actually provided through the SQLAlchemy Google Groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/YVAI4C94NBs